# Possible to display images and youtube video in email?

Tags: html, email

is it possible to display images and youtube videso in emails?

Example: if an email containing

```
<img src="img.jpg" /> and the youtube <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2ItZFNegL80" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Does it get display in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GMail, the YouTube link will automatically be expanded at the bottom of the message into a working video. Other clients may have similar functionality, but because JavaScript, HTML5 Video and Flash aren't supported by email clients, there's no general way for you to embed video.

If you want to include a preview image, you can build a URL for it from the video URL.

- Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_ID
- Image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_ID/0.jpg

For example:

- Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwFbjJasW3E
- Image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/OwFbjJasW3E/0.jpg